# Get call parameters from the returned MagicMock object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

Calling a method of a MagicMock object returns another MagicMock object.

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> mock = MagicMock()
>>> a = mock.foo('A', 1)
>>> a
<MagicMock name='mock.foo()' id='50553184'>
```

**Is it possible to get the call parameters (`'A', 1` in my example) from the returned object?**

The returned object was not called (only its parent was), so all those `*call*` methods and properties like `called`, `assert_called()` or `mock_calls` are not usable.

```
>>> del mock
>>> a
<MagicMock name='mock.foo()' id='50553184'>
>>> a.called
False
>>> a.mock_calls
[]
>>>
```

In my program, it is difficult to access the parent mock as it is an umpteenth child of the original MagicMock object I created. I’d find asserts on the returned object more convincing than finding the parent object through the hierarchy as it could result in inspecting a different call.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you can't and you are limited to test that all the calls are as expected or that the specific call is contained in the calls made, but you have to use the parent mock object to check that.